# Select pixel values in a raster using R

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, modis

I'm trying to select some cell values in a raster MODIS. Follow my problem:

I have to filter these values to mask after it: `32767,32766,32765,32764,32763,32762,32761`

I've used this code to one value:

```
water_mask <- water == 1
```

but when I do:

```
filter <- image == 32767,32766,32765,32764,32763,32762,32761
```

The following error appears:

Someone can help me?

[image]

Comment: Please do not paste screenshots of your code. Paste the code instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`32767,32766,32765,32764,32763,32762,32761` will never work. It isn't a vector, values must be inside `c()` function (`c(32767,32766,32765,32764,32763,32762,32761)`) at least to identify your error.

But, you should apply a logic test with `%in%` for multiple values and use this result to mask `image`:

```
filter_image <- image %in% 32761:32767

filter_image2 <- mask(image, filter_image, maskvalue = 1)
```

Comment: @NSilva you're welcome! Glad to help